# Convert number larger than 5

Tags: php, numbers

I want convert number larger than 5 become 1-5 again, ex:

```
6 become 1
7 become 2
8 become 3
9 become 4
```

so if I enter number 6-9 to my function, it will converted to above explanation.

```
my_function(6); //will become 1
my_function(7); //will become 2 and so on...
```

Comment: okay :) I'm still waiting for the time :D . You can accept an answer in 9 minutes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function my_function( $num ) {
    if ( $num % 5 === 0 ) {
         return 5;
    }
    return $num % 5;
}
```

The modulus operator `%` returns the remainder when one number is divided by another number.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [Modulus operator, `%`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php), it gives the remainder of a division.

```
function RangeOneToFive($num)
{
   // Without the subtract and add this would range 0 to 4.
   return (($num - 1) % 5) + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_function( $num ) {
    ( $num % 5 === 0 ) ? $num = 5 : $num = $num % 5;
    return $num;
}
```